# eslint-plugin-import order not working with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I'm trying to get the `import/order` rule from `eslint-plugin-import` to work in a React project using webpack but I'm struggling. Specifically with import grouping.

This is the part of my config where I've set up the rule:

```js
'import/order': [
  'error',
  {
    alphabetize: {
      order: 'asc',
      caseInsensitive: true,
    },
    groups: ['builtin', 'external', 'internal'],
    'newlines-between': 'always',
    pathGroups: [
      {
        pattern: '@app/**',
        group: 'internal',
        position: 'after',
      },
      {
        pattern: '@canopy/**',
        group: 'internal',
        position: 'after',
      },
      {
        pattern: '@titan/**',
        group: 'internal',
        position: 'after',
      },
    ],
  },
],
```

I'm also using the webpack resolver setting:

```js
'import/resolver': {
  webpack: {
    config: './config/webpack.config.app.js',
  },
},
```

The issue I'm having is that it treats relative file imports like internal ones (as it should) but also imports from external packages such as `React` or `lodash`.

It insists that they should be together like this:

```
import foo from './foo';
import React from 'react';
```

I have tried matching relative imports manually using `pathGroups` and glob patterns, but that didn't work reliably.

Comment: Please post what you expect the output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `typescript`

- make sure you have installed [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-import-resolver-typescript)
- configure `import/resolver`